# Use current web directory when navigating to page or url

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm updating a very old web app (webforms) that only works properly in IE 6-9. It was not originally written by me. Also, I'm not an expert at web development, so the solution to this might be very simple.

One issue is extensive use of `window.showModalDialog`, which is an IE specific call that opens a new browser window that disables the browser window that opened it, like a popup message. This has been replaced with a jquery modal dialog, however there's sometimes an issue with the 'url' that gets passed to it.

Here's a simplified reproduction of the issue. There's a javascript function that takes a url and an id.

```
function openEdit(url, id) { ...
```

This function existed in the original version, except it had code to open a modal popup window. I replaced it with the necessary jquery. However, the `url` value that gets passed in sometimes doesn't have enough information. Also, assume I have no control over the value that gets passed here.

Let's say the main page is at `localhost/TestSite/Main.aspx`. There are a number of frames within this page which display other pages, like `localhost/TestSite/Products/ProductList.aspx` - clicking an item on this page might open a window to `localhost/TestSite/Products/ProductDetails.aspx`. There are hundreds of pages that follow this general format.

Sometimes the `url` has a value of '/TestSite/Products/ProductDetails.aspx'. The jquery dialog correctly navigates to `localhost/TestSite/Products/ProductDetails.aspx`

However, other pages just pass in the name of the page, 'ProductDetails.aspx', which jquery tries to find at `localhost/TestSite/ProductDetails.aspx`. This works on IE using `window.showModalDialog` and the browser is able to get the expected directory of 'Product' because it's the same directory the open window call was made from. Jquery doesn't seem make this leap.

Now, I have a possible solution using `window.location` to get the current url, parse it a bit, and generate a valid url. I'm worried about what fringe cases this may create, though, and it also seemed like the improper way to do it.

Is there a way to have jquery open a dialog using the corrent directory, or is there a way to generate a current directory to use that doesn't involve `window.location`? Or is that my best choice.

Comment: `the browser is able to get the expected directory of 'Product' because it's the same directory the open window call was made from`
What do you mean by open window call?

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda I meant, when `showModalDialog`, the IE function, gets called it is able to deduce the url correctly, whereas the jquey dialog does not.